# iOS NSURLConnection Redirect 301 and Standard Caching

Tags: ios, http-status-code-301

If using the standard NSURL routines with no other changes, will the standard flags prevent the 301 Redirects from being saved / used?  Flags like:

```
NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData      // Unimplemented
NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData = NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad
NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataDontLoad
NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData                // Unimplemented
```

So, which ones will ignore / prevent the 301 redirects from being used and which ones will honor the 301 redirects with http://

Or are these only for data cache?

Answer (score 0):

This is what the specification HTTP 1.1 [Overview of Status Codes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-24#section-6.1) says to this matter:

> **6.1.  Overview of Status Codes**

> The status codes listed below are defined in this specification,
> Section 4 of [Part4], Section 4 of [Part5], and Section 3 of [Part7].
> The reason phrases listed here are only recommendations -- they can
> be replaced by local equivalents without affecting the protocol.

> Responses with status codes that are defined as cacheable by default
> (e.g., 200, 203, 206, 300, 301, and 410 in this specification) can be
> reused by a cache with heuristic expiration unless otherwise
> indicated by the method definition or explicit cache controls
> [Part6]; all other status codes are not cacheable by default.

However, I cannot tell with certainty and without further investigation how iOS NSURLConnection and NSURLCache will *actually* behave.

The option `NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy` -- which is the default -- **should** behave as specified above.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but was looking for what IOS is really doing under the hood.  Will post more information here as I research.